# Swift - How to toggle between Play and Pause with UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, toggle, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying with the below Swift code in my timer application to start and pause with the same button I have. But it is does not toggle. The button is set with Identifier as "Play" in the IDE. When I run the app, Timer starts and pauses correctly. But it does not toggle button. It always remain as "Play"

```
@IBAction func pressPausePlay(sender: AnyObject) {

    if playPause == false
    {
            timer.invalidate()
            self.playPauseButtonVar = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "pressPausePlay")

            playPause = true
    }
    else
    {
           timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

           self.playPauseButtonVar = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "pressPausePlay")

           playPause = false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Example scenarios to toggle between Play and Pause, for Button Titles, Image, Navigation Bar, ToolBar

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

      var myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


    @IBOutlet var myNaviBar: UINavigationBar! //OUTLET TO NAVIGATION BAR IMPORTANT TO WORK WITH ITS BARBUTTON ITEMS

    @IBOutlet var myToolBar: UIToolbar!


//**************START :Bottom LEFT TOOLBAR Bar Button Item***********/
    @IBAction func toolBarItemPlay(sender: AnyObject) {

        myToolBar.setItems([UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "toolBarItemPause:")], animated: true)
        myPlayer.play()
    }


    @IBAction func toolBarItemPause(sender: AnyObject) {

        myToolBar.setItems([UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "toolBarItemPlay:")], animated: true)
        myPlayer.pause()
    }
//**************END :Bottom LEFT TOOLBAR Bar Button Item***********/




//**************START :Top LEFT Naivation Bar Button Item***********/

    @IBAction func leftNavgationbarPlay(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        myNaviBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Pause, target: self, action: "leftNavigationbarPause:")
        myPlayer.play()
    }

    //no need of control drag to this one below because we are calling from the above leftNavgationbarPlay's Selector/action
    @IBAction func leftNavigationbarPause(sender : UIBarButtonItem) {
        myNaviBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Play, target: self, action: "leftNavgationbarPlay:")
        myPlayer.pause()
    }
//**************END :Top LEFT Naivation Bar Button Item***********/




//**************START :Top Right Naivation Bar Button Item***********/
    @IBAction func naviPlay(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        //change the topright navigation bar item from SystemItem Play '>' to systemitem pause '||'
        //  here I am assigning the top left item Play to Bar button item Pause

        /* ACTION SELECTOR IMPORTANT. IT MUST CALL THE IB ACTION FUNCTION OF PAUSE AND VICEVERSA, WITH ":" */
        myNaviBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "naviPause:")
        myPlayer.play()
    }

    @IBAction func naviPause(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    myNaviBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "naviPlay:")
      myPlayer.pause()
    }
//**************END : Top Right Naivation Bar Button Item***********/





//************START :BUTTON IMAGE CHANGE - ">"to "||"************//

    @IBAction func imagePlayButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let chkImage = sender.currentImage!
        if chkImage == UIImage(named: "play.png"){


            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), forState: .Normal)

            myPlayer.play()
        } else {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), forState: .Normal)
            myPlayer.pause()
        }

    }

//************END :BUTTON IMAGE CHANGE - ">"to "||"************//






//************START BUTTON TITLE CHANGE - PLAY to PAUSE************//

    @IBAction func playButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let chkTitle = sender.currentTitle
        if chkTitle == "Play" {
            sender.setTitle("Pause", forState: .Normal)
            myPlayer.play()
        } else {
            sender.setTitle("Play", forState: .Normal)
            myPlayer.pause()
        }

    }

//************END BUTTON TITLE CHANGE - PLAY to PAUSE************//




    @IBAction func naviStop(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        myPlayer.stop()
        myPlayer.currentTime = 0

    }

    @IBOutlet var sliderUI: UISlider!


    @IBAction func mySlider(sender: UISlider) {


        myPlayer.volume = sliderUI.value
    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let audioFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ARRehman", ofType: "mp3")

        //need NSURL from string

        do {
            myPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioFilePath!))

        }
        catch {
            print("Some error")

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: yes, yes, yes, yes, yes!!! i spent all night looking for this answer. This is the first one which solved my problem.

The key was the `IBOutlet` to the `UINavigationBar`!!!!

THANK YOU!

Comment: cheers :-) I have been in that position quite a few nights too, i can understand the feeling!

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace bar button items hold in UIToolbar after you assign a new instance to `self.playPauseButtonVar`.

If you have `toolBar` or `navigationBar` outlets:

```
self.toolBar.setItems([self.playPauseButtonVar], animated: true)
// Or
self.navigationBar.setItems([self.playPauseButtonVar], animated: true)
```

If your class inherits UIViewController:

```
self.setToolbarItems([self.playPauseButtonVar], animated: true)
// Or
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(self.playPauseButtonVar, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you Yoichi for the response. I tried it this way: Added an IBOutlet var for the tool bar in the view controller class. and added the above codes for toolbars (one at a time). It gave me the below error. 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Stop_Watch.ViewController 0x7af55250> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bottomToolBar.'

Now the error is not going away even after removing everything I added.

I am relatively new to iOS and Swift. 

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the name of the key in the error? Is it "bottomToolBar"? Probably you set something in "User Defined Runtime Attributes" section, which is in the 3rd page of the right pane in Xcode.

Comment: it says the variable I added (bottomToolBar) as the key. 

2015-03-09 21:12:43.696 Stop Watch[1956:189288] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Stop_Watch.ViewController 0x7ca916c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bottomToolBar.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: and the execution was seen as stopped at 

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

Comment: Check the storyboard or xib as source code. Right click on the file, then "Open As" > "Source Code". You can find where the key "bottomToolBar" is used.

Comment: Yoichi, thanks for pointing me to the correct place. I removed the references on the Tool bar Outlet variable (bottomToolBar) under "Referencing Outlets". That resolved the error. However I am not able to add the tool bar outlet again, if I add, the error comes back!

Comment: I'm not sure you are correctly connecting the outlet. Please try following this page to use Interface Builder to set an outlet. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2273069&seqNum=4

Answer (score 0):

Yoichi, thanks for pointing me to the correct place. I removed the references on the Tool bar Outlet variable (bottomToolBar) under "Referencing Outlets". That resolved the error. However I am not able to add the tool bar outlet again, if I add, the error comes back!

Answer (score 0):

it worked with me by creating bar button by code this is my code

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

@IBOutlet weak var displayCountLabel: UILabel!
var buttonPause = UIBarButtonItem()
var buttonPlay = UIBarButtonItem()
var count=0
var timer=NSTimer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buttonPause = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "pauseAction")
    buttonPlay = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "playAction")

    self.navigationBar?.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = buttonPlay

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func stopTimer(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
    count = 0
    displayCountLabel.text = "\(count)"
    self.navigationBar?.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = buttonPlay
}

func pauseAction() {
    self.navigationBar?.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = buttonPlay
    timer.invalidate()
}

func playAction() {
    self.navigationBar?.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = buttonPause
    timer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("displayCount"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func displayCount()
{
    count++
    displayCountLabel.text = "\(count)"
}
```

}